# Run jQuery AJAX when hitting 'enter / return'

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit, return

I have a simple form for users to post on a 'wall'. As you can see it has one text input field and a submit button that is made of multiple spans styled via CSS.

```
<form action="http://example.com/2/chat_share" method="post" id="chat_form">                    
<input type="text" name="chat_msg" value="" />                  
</form>

<span class="share_js fc-button fc-button-prev fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right">
    <span class="fc-button-inner">
        <span class="fc-button-content save_button">Share</span>
        <span class="fc-button-effect">
            <span></span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

This works nicely when the user clicks on the 'Share' button, which runs the AJAX below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.share_js').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var link = $('#chat_form').attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#chat_form').serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend: function(){
                  $('#loading').show();
                },          
            success: function() {
                $('#chat_thread').load(2 + '/chat_ajax');
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#chat_form input').val('');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

My problem is that when I hit 'return' or 'enter' on the keyboard, the form is submitted via the non-AJAX method.

I wanted to capture this keystroke using

```
$('#selector').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        //code
    }
})
```

but haven't been able to wrap this around my AJAX function.

**Ideally both clicking on Share and hitting return should submit the form.**

Anyone have suggestions how to do this?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why not using the form post?

```
<form action="http://example.com/2/chat_share" method="post" id="chat_form">                    
<input type="text" name="chat_msg" value="" />                  

<span class="share_js fc-button fc-button-prev fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right">
    <span class="fc-button-inner">
        <span class="fc-button-content save_button">Share</span>
        <span class="fc-button-effect">
            <span></span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
</form>
```

and then hook up the form POST

```
$('#chat_form').bind('submit', function(event) {

    var link = $(this).attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function(){
              $('#loading').show();
            },          
        success: function() {
            $('#chat_thread').load(2 + '/chat_ajax');
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#chat_form input').val('');
        }
    });

    return false; // dont post it automatically
});
```

---

from comments

```
$('.save_button').bind('click', function(event) {
    getStuff();
    return false; // dont move to top
});
$('#chat_form').bind('submit', function(event) {
    getStuff();
    return false; // dont post it automatically
});

function getStuff() {

    var link = $('#chat_form').attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#chat_form').serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function(){
              $('#loading').show();
            },          
        success: function() {
            $('#chat_thread').load(2 + '/chat_ajax');
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#chat_form input').val('');
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: thx @balexandre but this causes 2 issues - [1] my shar button gets disabled and [2] when i hit enter it still goes non-AJAX route

Comment: then you must have a javascript error somewhere that is preventing to the `submit` be hooked up with the method

Comment: @balexandre - is there a way of preserving the click on Share for submit also? since this is not a `<button>` it will be inactive by removing the `click` function

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the form submit event:

```
$('#chat_form').submit(function(){
    //do stuff
    return false;//prevent default submission.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `click` event to a form `submit` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#chat_form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var link = $('#chat_form').attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#chat_form').serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function(){
              $('#loading').show();
            },          
        success: function() {
            $('#chat_thread').load(2 + '/chat_ajax');
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#chat_form input').val('');
        }
    });
});

});
```

For the `keydown`, you could do this:

```
$('#selector').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
e.preventDefault();
$('#chat_form').trigger('submit');
        //code
    }
})
```

Comment: similar to @balexandre's sample, although I get no errors, this does not allow the option for clicking on Share **and** hitting enter

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to use 2 separate methods for each situation: one for clicking on `Share` and one for hitting the enter / return keys.

This code works for me, but please let me know if you think this represents unnecessary bloat or  lines -- otherwise I'll later mark this as the final answer.

Thanks to all for helping.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


//this  will run AJAX when clicking on 'Share'


    $('.share_js').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var link = $('#chat_form').attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#chat_form').serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend: function(){
                  $('#loading').show();
                },          
            success: function() {
                $('#chat_thread').load(<?php echo $id; ?> + '/chat_ajax');
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#chat_form input').val('');
            }
        });
    });

//this  will run AJAX when hitting return / enter

    $('#chat_form input').keydown(function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
    e.preventDefault();

        var link = $('#chat_form').attr('action');

            $.ajax({
                url: link,
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#chat_form').serialize(),
                dataType: "html",
                beforeSend: function(){
                      $('#loading').show();
                    },          
                success: function() {
                    $('#chat_thread').load(<?php echo $id; ?> + '/chat_ajax');
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#chat_form input').val('');
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```